# Toggle radio button within a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

I am taking the index of the selected cell to display a selected radio button image. It works just fine, but once I attempt to select a cell that contains the selected radio button it will not deselect with the unselected radio button image:

```
if indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex {
     cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_selected"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
} else {
     cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_unselected"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

How could I revise this code so that I can toggle the image On/Off, on selection of the same cell?

Comment: put  your setImage function into the didSelectRow override

Comment: Elaborate? @ÖzgürErsil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` check for already selected cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      if self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
          self.selectedIndex = -1
      }
      else {
          self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
      }
      self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)

Comment: @SaiPavanParanam Welcome mate :)

Comment: But there is one problem with the above code, even we can deselect the already selected radio button.

Comment: @ArshadShaik you can set yourButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false when button is selected so when you tap on selected button nothing happen